# find and replace string with line breaks across files

Tags: html, regex, vba, replace, ms-word

Hello I am trying to replace a string across multiple html files something like this

sample text

sample text

white space

sample text

word find and replace has a character limit and so does notepad++. The white spaces are causing problems and 
so far the macro for this is not working

```
Sub TEST()
'
' TEST Macro
'
'
 Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object, rngStory As Object
    Dim sFolder As String, strFilePattern As String
    Dim StrFileName As String, sFileName As String

'~~> Change this to the folder which has the files
sFolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\vbtest"
'~~> This is the extention you want to go in for
strFilePattern = "*.htm"

'~~> Establish an Word application object
On Error Resume Next
Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

oWordApp.Visible = True

'~~> Loop through the folder to get the htm files
StrFileName = Dir$(sFolder & strFilePattern)
Do Until StrFileName = ""
    sFileName = sFolder & StrFileName

    '~~> Open the word doc
    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)

    '~~> Do Find and Replace
    For Each rngStory In oWordDoc.StoryRanges
        With rngStory.Find
            .Text = "/(sample text)\n(sample text)\n(sample text)\n[\s].*(sample text)/"
            .Replacement.Text = "/(sample text2)\n(sample text2)\n(sample text2)\n[\s].*(sample text2)/"
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next

    '~~> Close the file after saving
    oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True

    '~~> Find next file
    StrFileName = Dir$()
Loop

'~~> Quit and clean up
oWordApp.Quit

Set oWordDoc = Nothing
Set oWordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

just tried this with regex not working

Comment: Show the macro please.

Comment: You can write a regex to search through your files, something like `/(sample text)\n(sample text)\n(sample text)\n[\s].*(sample text)/`